# Specify that a method does not modify a class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
class A {
  x: number
  set(x: number) { this.x = x }
  get() { return this.x }
}
```

I would like to be able to pass around an `Immutable<A>` (or similar).

```
// imagined Typescript
const a: A = new A()
a.set(5)
a.get()

const a: Immutable<A> = new A()
a.set(5) // ILLEGAL!
a.get()
```

---

I'm used to writing C++ where I can specify whether a method mutates a class or not:

```
struct A {
  int x;
  int get() const { return x; }; // this method does not mutate A
  void set(int newX) { x = newX; };
};
```

This makes it easy to create an immutable or readonly reference to an object. Some users can mutate the object. Other users get a `const &` reference to the object and cannot mutate the object.

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

  A a;
  a.get();
  a.set(4);

  A const & constA = a;
  constA.get();
  constA.set(4); // THIS IS ILLEGAL
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option would be to create a read-only interface that doesn't have the `set` method. `A` would implement that interface.

```
interface IA {
  get();
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const a: IA = new A()
```

Comment: @coda i'm not sure what that code would prohibit you.

Comment: Thanks!

(My earlier comment wasn't finished :))